# Ребят пытаюсь настроить отправку отложенных сообщений для телеграмма в python. Help mi

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-3.5

**Вот пример**

```
await bot.send_photo(
                    chat_id=-1002013395422,
                    photo=base64.b64decode(base64_string),
                    caption = str(data[2]),
                    date = 1708592400)
и
wait bot.send_message(
                          chat_id=-1002013395422,
                          text = str(data[2][1010:]),
                          date = 1708592400)
в технической документации по api есть такой параметр date у сообщений. А всё равно не отправляет в отложенные с датой публикации.
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Это где такой параметр есть? Может юзерботы могут отправлять отложенные сообщения. Используйте средства Python